# Displaying images from database using php. Not showing image

Tags: php, html

I have images in a database that I am trying to display.  when I enter the code  I am seeing the picture name like I want but the picture shows up as a broken link.

the database names, tables and columns are all labeled correctly.  I am properly displaying the picture name just not the picture.

```
<?php
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','*******','images') or die($mysqli->connect_error);
        $table = 'hairportfolio';

        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $table") or die($mysqli->error);



        while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<h2>{$data['name']}</h2>";
            echo "<img src='{$data['img']}' width='40%' height='40%'>";
        }

        ?>
```

I should be seeing the image but I just see a broken link.

Comment: So when you say you have the images in the database you mean you have a string that is the URL to the image's actual location? Can you add an example of how the image URI comes out?

Comment: 13     D:xampphtdocsHairbycourtneyuploads/13.jpg    Thats how it looks in the database.  the 13 is the name and then the file url

Comment: In that case check the file/folder permissions for that location to make sure the files can be accessed. I'm assuming the missing slashes is simply SO formatting related.

Comment: Yeah its SO formatted related.  The permissions are good......

Comment: The URL doesn't need to include the xampp/htdocs part, it should just be relative to the root of your site. So if 'Hairbycourtney' is the base folder, the URL just needs to be '/images/13.jpg'. Test that in the browser by going to whatever port/url the site is on and just appending '/images/13.jpg'

Comment: I changed to just /images/.  Still same issue.....pictures are uploading but not displaying

Comment: OK, so if you load the website and go to localhost:<PORT>/images/13.jpg (or whatever the site URL is) do you see the image in the browser? If not then something is definitely wrong with the path or permissions, not the code.